# Searching for whole URL using elastic4s

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

I'm using elastic4s in order to index and search data in ES. Part of the document I'm storing contains a url field which I need to search for (the entire url). The problem occurs when I search for a document containing the url field and get 0 results.

For the purpose of this search I define a mapping ahead of inserting the data into the index:

```
client.execute {
  create index <my_index> mappings {
    <my_type> as {
      "url" typed StringType analyzer NotAnalyzed
    }
  }
}
```

I'm inserting the data:

```
client.execute { index into <my_index> -> <my_type> fields (
  "url" -> "http://sample.com"
  )
}.await
```

And I search for the documents:

```
val filter =
"""
  |{
  |    "filtered" : {
  |        "query" : {
  |            "match_all" : {}
  |        },
  |        "filter" : {
  |            "bool" : {
  |              "should" : [
  |                { "bool" : {
  |                  "must" : [
  |                     { "term" : { "url" : "http://sample.com" } }
  |                  ]
  |                } }
  |              ]
  |            }
  |        }
  |    }
  |}
""".stripMargin

client.execute { search in <my_index> -> <my_type> rawQuery { filter } }.await
```

I get 0 results after executing this query. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

In the mapping, instead of doing:

```
client.execute {
  create index <my_index> mappings {
    <my_type> as {
      "url" typed StringType analyzer NotAnalyzed
    }
  }
}
```

I should have done:

```
client.execute {
  create index <my_index> mappings {
    <my_type> as {
      "url" typed StringType index "not_analyzed"
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
client.execute {
  create index <my_index> mappings {
    <my_type> as {
      "url" typed StringType index NotAnalyzed
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your query can be simplified a bit, to something like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "url": {
        "value": "http://example.com"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Weirdly, I would expect your query to return all documents, due to the nesting of your boolean queries. `should` means documents that match any query in the array are scored higher than those not matching. So, a `should` containing only one `must` should return all documents, with matching documents scored higher than non matching.

Comment: You're right regarding simplifying the query. The actual query is a bit bigger, I just wanted it to maintain it's structure for purposes of reproduction.
At first, it wasn't returning results because I didn't define a mapping for the 'url' field and did not tell ES it was a non analyzed field. So, the standard ES analyzer broke the url into several tokens and didn't match on the entire field. After telling it it was not a analyzed field, it should have matched on the entire field.